# JNDI pooled data source: Driver-based vs DataSource-based

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jndi, hikaricp

I'm looking to set up Tomcat to use a JNDI pooled data source for a MySQL database. HikariCP seems to be the recommended choice recently ([at least on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955875#21125176)).

The documentation helpfully [lists the configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-(Tomcat,-etc.)) (presumably for server.xml or context.xml) but divides into "Driver-based" and "DataSource-based". Couldn't find much more info about this - could anyone advise on how to make the choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things being equal, I'd go with DataSource-based.  With Driver-based the driver is basically wrapped as a DataSource internally -- so it adds an extra layer (thin though it may be).

However, all things are not always equal.  Sometimes there are drivers that expose *some* settings as URL parameters but not as DataSource properties.  Most drivers are good about equivalency.  So, if you happen to need to tweak a setting that is only available as a URL parameter, you'll have no choice but to use the Driver-based approach.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Don't suppose you'd be able to comment specifically about [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)?

Comment: The Connector/J documentation states, "Unless otherwise noted, properties can be set for a DataSource object or for a Connection object."  However, I was unable to find any "noted" examples.  I suspect that almost all properties are exposed on the DataSource.  It's pretty easy to determine though, if you get an exception trying to use a specific property then you know it's not supported. :)